# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list) during model fitting

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I know these types of questions have been asked already. But in them, I didn't find a solution to my problem. I just don't know why it is showing me this error.

I have a airline kaggle dataset, I have cleaned it:

[image]

Data type of cleaned column is like this:

[image]

I converted the labels in integers with this piece of code:

```
data['sentiment']=data['airline_sentiment'].apply(lambda x: -1 if (x=="negative") else (0 if (x=="neutral") else 1))
```

data['sentiment'] is also `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

While model fitting it was showing me the same error as mentioned i.e. `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).` . So I tried to change the individual columns to tensor myself like this:

```
data['text_'] = tf.convert_to_tensor(data['text_'])
print(type(data['text_']))
```

But unfortunately I got the same error. I don't know why it is happening , I'm not using or converting anything to numpy in my whole code. After this I tried converting `data['text_']` to numpy too using `.to_numpy()` property. It worked but when I print the `type(data['text_'])` , I get the same data type of pandas series,i.e. I think it is not changing the datatype of that column inplace.

How can I solve this error. Please tell me If you need more info related to code. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try `tf.convert_to_tensor( data[ 'text_' ].values )`?

Comment: No, let me try and I will get back to you

Comment: No ,it is showing me the same error

Comment: The column (Series) contains lists of strings, lists that vary in length.

Comment: are you talking about data['text_'], if yes then how it can hinder between change of data type

Comment: @hpaulj I was trying some different methods and I think you are right about different lengths of lists. How can I correct it as different lists contain different strings and I think changing them with an empty string will also not be a good choice as It might alter with accuracy of model. Also, Why they want list of same length. I tried converting only single list from them ,but it showed that it doesnot match the dimension of last list in array of lists.

Comment: You need to spend more time learning what `keras` expects for this kind of "fitting".  `"tensors" can be created from multidimensional numeric arrays, because the fitting uses some sort of numerical calculation.  A list of lists of strings of varying lengths clearly does not fit this model.  Be careful when working from tutorials that don't explain the basics.  It's easy to get lost if you stray from the exact path laid out by the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! for the advice. I have already found out the mistake and solved it.